# Convert C# HMAC SHA256 to work on Windows 8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Trying to convert this code to work on a universal app...

```
namespace Test
{
  public class MyHmac
  {
    private string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
    {
      secret = secret ?? "";
      var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
      byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
      using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
      {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and I'm having trouble finding where HMACSHA256 (or a similar class) lives in the new framework as `System.Security.Cryptography` isn't available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with hmacsha256 in windows store app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293420/working-with-hmacsha256-in-windows-store-app)

Answer (score 0):

The cryptography namespace for Windows Store Apps is Windows.Security.Cryptography
and Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core

The new Hash Algorithm Provider supports several algorithms (including SHA256)

There are some nice examples here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider

-Achod